# ADK v21 not working

Tags: android

This Q is asked many times ans answered many times but even though no answer worked for me ... So asking again ..

I am on Win 8 64 Bit, JDK 32 + 64 Bit installed, Eclipse JRE 32 Bit and A SDK 32 Bit.
When I am using SDK v20 no problem 
When I updated to SDK v21 problem starts ...
Eclipse start saying no SDK installed...
SDK manager Starts & Closes instantly...

Tried following things

- Changing Java path from path Environment variable
- Altering Android.bat file
- Deleting .android folder from c:\users\\ folder
- Tried Latest ADT Bundle Latest x86

but none worked

So I am reverting back to SDK v20 working fine ...

Any one have any other solution ... Should I stick to SDK v20 ?

==v2==

Tried to update Eclipse Plugin as suggested by m0skit0

from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

getting error

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt,8.1.1.201209170703
No repository found containing:

Comment: did you also update your eclipse and your adt plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[Install ADK Eclipse plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). Install the ADK from Eclipe's Android SDK Manager. Use that to update, and don't forget to update the Elipse plugin from time to time.

Comment: Getting this error

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt,8.1.1.201209170703
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers,1.1.0.201209170703

Comment: Uncheck *"Contact all update sites during install to find required software"* and try again.